# Is restarting a QThread after calling quit legal and sensible?

Tags: multithreading, qt

According to the Qt manual on `QThread` the `quit()` function waits for the current task to terminate and then ends the event loop. 
After having called `quit()` and `wait()` for proper termination, 
is it legal to start the same instance of the QThread again using `start()`.
The code seems to be working all right but after a restart the Thread ID changes.
There is no mention of this in the docs and all examples seem to create a new Thread instance or don't call quit, so I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's legal to start a thread again if it was properly stopped.

And this is what [the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThreadId) says about thread id (emphasis mine):

> Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId()
>
> Returns the thread handle of the currently executing thread.
>
> Warning: The handle returned by this function is used for internal
>   purposes **and should not be used in any application code**.

So you should not care about thread id change.